# Remove Execution plan cache from Sybase IQ

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-iq

how can I remove execution plan cache for a specific query from sybase iq

Comment: here is how to do it in SQL Server https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx

Comment: SQL Server is related to Sybase ASE, not IQ, so that doesn't really help.  Sybase IQ is based on SQL Anywhere.

Comment: Hi - I see you've been on SO recently, but have not yet accepted my answer, or made any comments.  Please make sure you upvote helpful answers, and accept answers to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change the setting for `max_plans_cached` option to 0 to disable the caching of plans.  When reenabled, the optimizer should recompute the plans as the queries are executed.

[This is a good description](http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbusage/plan-caching-queryopt.html) of the plan caching methods in SQL Anywhere 12, which should be fairly close to the same in IQ.